# Confusion on Countability of Rationls

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

As I've been working on an Analysis problem, I have confused myself utterly while thinking about the rationals as a subset of the reals. It is common knowledge that the rationals are countably infinite, we can list them off in a sequence. But how does this not lead to a contradiction? If we can number the rationals, then we can number a subset $ A \subset \mathbb{Q}$ of them in an ordered sequence, say $  A = \{q_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, so $ q_1 < q_2 < \cdots $.  Then for an arbitrary element, $ q_i$, with $ i>1$ look at the midpoint between its 'neighbor' $q_{i+1}$. But this value $ x = \frac{q_i+q_{i+1}}{2} $ must be rational, since the rationals are closed under addition and multiplication, but it must also be in $ \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$, since we ordered the set $D$. What is going wrong here? I assume it's the stage where I ordered the rationals, as it doesn't make sense for rationals to be "next to each other", just as no two reals are "next to each other", since we can always take the median, which is a real number. Some clarification would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Suppose we take some rational $ q_1 $, then let $ A = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q}: x >= q_1 \}$.

Comment: "If we can number the rationals, then we can number a subset $A\subset\mathbb Q$ of them in an ordered sequence..." Sure we can put the rationals in a sequence, but who says it's possible for that sequence to respect the rationals' ordering?

Comment: In fact didn't you select a _subset_ of the rationals to make your set $A$? So then you find out it is a proper subset (there are rationals not in $A$). What is so paradoxical about that?

Comment: You are correct. I have edited my question to address your response and more accurately reflect my intentions.

Comment: The midpoint of two rationals is itself a rational, NOT an irrational as you state; so it too appears somewhere in the sequence. What's contradictory about that? (nothing)

Comment: The edit just made the question self-contradictory. Now you are defining $A$ in two different ways that are inconsistent with each other.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing to do between the enumeration of the rationals and their ordering as real numbers.

$\frac{q_i+q_{i+1}}2$ can be $q_0$ or it can be $q_{42}$ or it can happen to be $q_{i+2}$. It does not matter one bit. The important thing is that we *can* in fact enumerate the rational numbers.

So the main confusion is that it is not at all true that $q_1<q_2<q_3<\ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of countably infinite set is ONLY that there exists a bijective correspondence between the set and the positive integer. However that bijective may or may not be order-preserving. Even though it seems like there are much more rationals than natural numbers, their cardinality is actually the same.

So the problem that leads to your confusion is that, countable=able to list them out. But the listing may not preserve the ordering.

Edit: btw the usual way to list out all rationals uses the fact that $\mathbb Z^+ \times \mathbb Z^+$ is bijective to $\mathbb Z^+$, let's say $B(n)=(p,q)$. Since for any $p,q\in \mathbb Z^+$, $\frac p q$ is a rational. And we can assign $f((p,q))=\frac pq$, then $f(B(n))$ is a surjective function mapping from $\mathbb Z^+$ to $\mathbb Q^+$

Comment: In fact, it's guaranteed that an enumeration of the rationals will *not* be order-preserving.